# Cannot remove element although id of element is right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on map it add element to map div, this row:

```
$('#map').append('<label>test:</label><input type="hidden" name="map_coords" id="' + e.latlng.lat + '" value="' + e.latlng.lat + '|' + e.latlng.lng + '"/>');
```

But when I click again it doesn't remove it with this row:

```
console.log(e.latlng.lat);
$('#'+e.latlng.lat).remove();
```

With `console.log(e.latlng.lat);` I'm sure that id of element is right, but it doesn't remove hidden input element.

`console.log($('#'+e.latlng.lat));` also returns me that there is element.

```js
var mymap = L.map('map').setView([42.148271, 24.750240], 17);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#map').css('width', $('.vc_custom_1538133669144').width());
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        accessToken: 'not-needed',
    }).addTo(mymap)

    L.marker([42.148271, 24.750240]).addTo(mymap);

    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
});

function onMapClick(e) {
    $('#map').append('<label>test:</label><input type="hidden" name="map_coords" id="' + e.latlng.lat + '" value="' + e.latlng.lat + '|' + e.latlng.lng + '"/>');
    var marker = L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]).addTo(mymap);
    marker.on('click',function(e) {
        console.log(e.latlng.lat);
        $('#'+e.latlng.lat).remove();
        this.remove();
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map" style="height: 500px;">

</div>
```

Comment: can you show the resulting html please (ie the html with the rendered attributes).  Also you would only remove the hidden input with that click as that is the thing with the id (not the label you also append).  If you want to remove both elements, then wrap it in a div with that id

Comment: Probably becouse the #id should be start with a letter... `ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ID contains special characters (in particular a dot). See [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> If the id contains characters like periods or colons you have to escape those characters with backslashes.

(This is because `.` would be interpreted as class selector: `#42.123456` means to select elements with ID `42` and class `123456` for example.)

Also, it starts with a number, which isn't technically allowed (see [point 6.2 here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40-971218/types.html)):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")

...however, it still works in all browsers I've tested.

You have a few options:

- You could escape the dot with backslashes: `$('#' + e.latlng.lat.toString().replace('.', '\\.')).remove()`
- You could query `[id="..."]` instead: `$('[id="' + e.latlng.lat + '"]').remove()`
- You could use `document.getElementById`: `$(document.getElementById(e.latlng.lat)).remove()`.

In my opinion a value like this shouldn't be an ID anyway though, I'd use a data attribute instead or simply keep a reference to the element directly:

```js
var $element = $('<div><label>test:</label><input type="hidden" name="map_coords" value="' + e.latlng.lat + '|' + e.latlng.lng + '"/></div>');
$('#map').append($element);

var marker = L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]).addTo(mymap);
marker.on('click',function(e) {
    $element.remove();
    this.remove();
});
```

Note that I also wrapped the elements in a `<div>` here! Actually, without it, it wouldn't even have worked in the first place, since the element you remove would be only the `<input>` and not the `<label>`.

Comment: Thank you, if you want provide and `data-attr` solution for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

I can click the map twice on the same location. The marker disappears on the second click.

However, because it is quite hard to click on the same lattitude coordinate it may look that the marker is not removing. Then that's because an other marker is placed on that new location.